# Opening Google Chrome from terminal on macOS causes no text rendering in browser

Tags: bash, macos, google-chrome

You can see on the screenshot what the problem looks like. When I start chrome from Dock, the problem doesn't appear. The same problem in chronium.

[image]

Commands I used to start browser:

```
open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
open -a "Google Chrome"
open -a Google\ Chrome
```

macOS High Sierra 10.13.6
Google Chrome 67.0.3396.99

Comment: I just tried open -a "Google Chrome" on the terminal and it opened fine.  Have you tried it with the quotes?

Comment: @jmh yes, I had tried this too - the same result.

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed under this GitHub post found from a Google hit result [Chrome shows no text when started by chromedriver #183](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/183#issuecomment-401820926).

Apparently they suggest something got broken in the most recent chrome-driver version of `2.40`, their suggestion was so start `Chrome` with `--disable-gpu` set, which you can do from the terminal as below. The `--disable-gpu` apparently disables hardware acceleration using the GPU.

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-gpu
```

or open it directly from the `/Applications/`

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --disable-gpu
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is the following :

```
/usr/bin/open -a "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" 'http://google.com/'
```

Another alternative is to add it to `bash.profile` as follows:

- Open `~/.bash_profile` in your editor of choice.
- Append this to the bottom of your `~/.bash_profile`:

  chrome () {
      open -a "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome" "$1"
    }

  - Save and close the file.
- Run source `~/.bash_profile` from the terminal to reload it.
- Enjoy being able to type things like `chrome http://google.com/` from the terminal.

We can also set Chrome as the default browser and execute the following command :

```
  open http://google.com/
```